# Wkhtmltopdf 0.12 (with patched qt) generates blank pages in pdf

Tags: php, pdf, wkhtmltopdf

I have used the wkhtmltopdf tool to generate pdf from html.
But i got some blank pages after few pages this thing repeats in whole pdf after some pages and i also got the wrong indexes in pdf due to this issue.

Please provide any solution for this problem.

Comment: Please provide some code for this problem.

Comment: I have uses three HTML files to generate single PDF with wkhtmltopdf and my code is here:  "Path to wkhtmltopdf tool First URL Second URL Third URL File Name 2>&1";

Comment: My Code is here:  $cmd = "/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf '".$pdf_html1."' '".$pdf_html2."' '".$pdf_html3."' $pdf_upload_path/$file_name 2>&1";
exec($cmd);